# I want to remove WordPress Nav container in small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, nav

My question is how to remove WordPress Nav container form <767 Screen? My current code is :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'main-nav', 'container' => 'nav', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
```

I want this to:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'main-nav', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
```

in small screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
    .main-nav{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to change "container", not "container_class"!